# jquery post a file form, but server get nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

i have a page need to click a button to post a file, but the server get nothing??? can anyone help me?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="upload_item">上传</button>

$('#upload_item').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = $('<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" hidden> </form>').wrapInner(
    $('<input type="file" value="" name="uploadfile">').click()).appendTo('body').submit().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are generating new DOM so instead of click event use **$(document).on();** Thus you would able to handle the events for newly generated DOM. Hope following Scripts will work for you.

```
$(document).on('click', '#upload_item', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var form = $('<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >  </form>').wrapInner(
                    $('<input type="file" value="" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile">'
                    )).appendTo('body').hide();

     var fileHandler = $('#uploadfile');
     fileHandler.click();                    
     fileHandler.change(function(event) {
        $(this).val();
        console.log($(this).val()); // Just Checking file is populated or not 
        form.submit();
      });
});
```

**And ++ if the problem is on server side to debug:**

How do you check on server to get the value of this form ? 
Are you using $_POST or $_FILES ?

Try the following code on your server side code. (This is for php)

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Analyse what you get on response. You will get a response like that

```
 array (size=1)
  'uploadfile' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
```

Check which error is creating this issue. [File Upload error Messages](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I'm assuming he is using python because there's a `django` tag for his question.

Comment: I guess its happening because, before selecting a file its submitting the form to the server. He triggered click() event in input file and after that submit the form. There is no checking form will submit after selecting a file. 
So he might need to check a file is selected, if selected only then submit the form.

Comment: i use django  web framework and i try this method,  on sever side, it work fine, Many thanks to you for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do this? if form is **hidden** how user will be able to click?
Obviously no file will be uploaded.

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" value="" name="uploadfile">
</form>
```

Comment: I agree it would be bad practice as well to allow files to be uploaded without some type of validation on the client side. Also give the user some way of changing the file they upload if they select the wrong one.

Comment: @LegenJerry exactly ,but he should explain more  what he wants to do